# Trouble Importing Neo4j in Java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, import, neo4j

I am doing a Maven project with Intellj Idea in which I am trying to use neo4j.

I have an error of "unable resolve symbol neo4j" on (import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;).

I have brought in the neo4j jar files to the project and believe I have a correctly set up pom file. I will post both though with this question below.

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>NeoImport</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>NeoImport</name>
<description>Import</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
</build>

</project>
```

Project Setup:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "brought the jars into the project"? In Maven, you specify a repository, write a pom and then get the dependencies automatically if you build.

Comment: Well I brought then in manually to the project cause it was recognizing it. How do I go about seeing the specified maven repo?

Comment: If you are connected to the internet, Maven should grab the dependency from Maven Central (it seems to be in there). I do not use IntelliJ, but there is surely some way to mark a project as Maven Project and then build it with something like mvn clean install.